# Can someone show me how to create this very simple makefile?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, makefile

This is in C, am running UNIX through Putty and want to create a Makefile.

So I have a program that is in only one file "recommender.c" and i need to make a makefile that creates an executable file called recommender using the all function. The part i don't know how to do is that i compile recommender.c using the line gcc recommender.c -std=gnu99
I don't know how to make sure it does the -std=gun99 part too. please help? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -O3

all: recommender

recommender: recommender.o
```

Note that the file extension must be `.c` if it has the extension `.cpp` it will need the `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`

Some explanation:

The make file is dependency based as you can see you can set your variables on top of the make file. Then when the make program is invoked it will search for a `Makefile` in the current directory.

Since the default action is `all` it will search for the all rule.
When it found the `all` rule it will check which dependencies are needed in this case the `recommender` rule / file so it starts searching the rules again and it finds out it needs the `recommender.o` rule / file but it won't find any, now here is where the magic happens.

`make` is smart enough to know that an .o (object) file is made from an .c or .cpp (source) file so now it will start searching for the source file in the current directory. This he does by replacing the `.o` with an `.c` if it finds the file it will compile it with the gcc compiler if it where to find an `.cpp` file it will compile it with the g++ compiler.

So now we know this we can simply add multiple source files to the project by adding more object file as dependencies.

Now you don't really need to create an object file first since you compile from one source file you can also remove the `recommender: recommender.o` rule and make will try to create the `recommender` application by compiling `recommender.c` or `.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a makefile;  `CFLAGS="-std=gnu99" make recommender` should "just work".

Comment: But the `Makefile` is very helpful for never forgetting the `CFLAGS`. :)

Comment: Might as well just manually type the compilation command; you don't even need make then.