# Getting a simple Makefile to work

Tags: c, makefile

So I'm having trouble getting even a simple Makefile to work. Heres what I have:

```
proj : driver.o
    icc -g -O3 -openmp driver.o -o proj
driver.o : driver.c driver.h
    icc -g -O3 -openmp driver.c
```

I feel like it's pretty straight forward. Proj only depends on driver.o which in turn depends on driver.c and driver.h. When run, the compiler fails with 'could not open source file "driver.h" ' at the include within the driver.c file. What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024679/can-someone-show-me-how-to-create-this-very-simple-makefile/6024703#6024703 In your case you will have to add CC=icc on top and change the names. Further more you will never have to add header files to the compiler.

Comment: The line `icc -g -O3 -openmp driver.c` does not tell the compiler to generate an object file. It will probably try to create an executable, very likely with a default name (e.g. a.out). You probably need to add `-c` to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you run `make` from the directory where all source files and headers reside, make sure you use quotes in your include directive:

```
#include "driver.h"
```

...rather than:

```
#include <driver.h>
```

The latter will search the system include path (and you will have to add the current directory to that path as larsmans suggested).

Comment: Thanks, looks like this was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should give `icc` a `-I.` option to get it to look for include files in the current directory.

```
icc -I. -c -g -O3 -openmp driver.c
```

(I took the liberty of also adding the `-c` flag to prevent linking.)

Comment: Not sure about icc, but shouldn't the current working directory be in the lookup paths anyway?

Comment: @Mario: only if the OP includes the file as `"driver.h"`; not if he uses `<driver.h>`.

Comment: Well, I'd rather replace the brackets then (incorrect use in my opinion).

Comment: @Mario: That's a matter of style. I like to use `""` for internal headers and `<>` for those exposed to the outside world (when writing a library).

Answer (score 1):

Is it in the correct folder? also the way you're compiling you might have to add `-c` to the command line to compile `driver.o` instead of trying to create a complete exectuable (only used to gcc so this might not be required).

Other than that (and the possible addition of the `-I` flag larsmans mentioned I can't see any other issue.